# AS3 Graph Api -> Popup Blocked

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, popup

we developed an as3 facebook application (http://www.encuentratugemelo.cl), but unfortunately the authenification popup is blocked in all major browsers (ie, ff, chrome), which leads to a high rejection rate for our campaign.
If I have a look here ... http://www.newxv.cl/setomatumuro/
These fellows used the same api (http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/), I checked it with a decompiler and their popup is never blocked!
Can anybody point me into a direcction what we can do that the popup is not blocked?

Gracias y cheers, 
Dennis

Comment: well, we faced the same problem in our project as well, suddenly the facebook pop window stopped, there are some small changes in API, i haven't worked on the issue, ma subordinate has worked on correcting this, when we login, there are some "param", change it to "scope", and go through the api once again

Comment: sorry i don't remember verything right now, but do work on changing the thing mentioned above, if it doesn't work, comment here, i'll give u smthing tmrrow :)

Comment: thank you for your comments.  which changes exactly we have to make? Where do I have to change "scope"? Maybe somebody can provide me a basic working fb connect class? Thank you , Dennis

Answer (score 2):

First you need to download the updated Facebook actionscript api frm here

> http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc&can=2&q=

Then in your code, where you have written this code :

```
Facebook.login(loginHandler,{scope:"user_birthday,user_photos,read_stream, publish_stream"});
```

Earlier we had this line in our code:

```
Facebook.login(loginHandler,{perms:"user_birthday,user_photos,read_stream, publish_stream"});
```

**Note :** Please change **perms** to **scope**

and finally, in the html pr php page, where you'll embed this swf:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <!-- Include support librarys first -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>             

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            //Note we are passing in attribute object with a 'name' property that is same value as the 'id'. This is REQUIRED for Chrome/Mozilla browsers       
            swfobject.embedSWF("FBEmbedTool.swf", "FlashContent", "1003", "600", "9.0", null, null, null, {name:"FlashContent"});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div><!-- required div tag -->
        <div id="FlashContent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will be helpful i guess, please do this, after making these changes, we had a running Fb api in our project.

Have a gr8 time, take care

Comment: I did exactly but still having issues with Chrome and IE, it's fine with Safari and Firefox, can you please further advise